# Unhealthy WorkerRole on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I have terrible problem with WorkerRole instance on Windows Azure. I have a Windows Azure projct that contains WebRole and WorkerRole.

The problem is, the WorkerRole instance is Unhealthy. The Error on a server:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-18T21:29:18.000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>864</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
   <Computer>RD00155D3A4A2E</Computer> 
 <Security /> 
</System>
<EventData>
 <Data>WaHostBootstrapper.exe</Data> 
 <Data>6.0.6002.18488</Data> 
 <Data>505cf7da</Data> 
 <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
 <Data>6.0.6002.18520</Data> 
 <Data>4e811810</Data> 
 <Data>c0000374</Data> 
 <Data>00000000000acb47</Data> 
 <Data>ae8</Data> 
 <Data>01ce0e1ef01200d9</Data> 
 </EventData>
</Event>
```

Faulting application WaHostBootstrapper.exe

Can somebody help me ?

p.s Project works perfect on local machine.

Comment: "Can somebody help me ?" -- what do you think? You haven't posted any code, only an error message. I think it's not sufficient.

Comment: So what do you want to see? WorkerRole.cs code? I know only that my instance is umhealthy and that the problem is connected to WaHostBootstrapper.exe. There is all the information I have got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on your machine but failed on the cloud it might because you miss some assemblies or dependency component.

You can enable the IntelliTrace when deploying so that later you can download the debug file and this might includes the actual exception/error for your worker role. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683671.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to install VS Ultimate and test it.